# How does postgres order the results when ORDER BY is not provided

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-order-by

Let's say I have two tables:

```
user (user_name varchar(50), project_name varchar(50))
project (project_name varchar(50), project_cost(integer))
```

I have a query that's returns me results which are "de-facto desired" :

```
select u.user_name, p.project_name 
from user u, project p 
where u.project_name = p.project_name
```

Postgres says that order of rows is not predictable when ORDER BY is not given. But yet in my local test, postgres returns rows in a same order for repeated tests.

Could you please help me understand what Postgres really does when `order by` is not provided in the query?

I don't have access to all the possible places where the real table and schema a live, so I really need to know what really happens in order to keep existing ordering intact.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If no `order by` clause is given, postgres (and any other reasonable database, for that sake), should return the rows in the order it was able to produce them (be it from an internal cache, an index, or directly from the table).

Since the same algorithm is used on the same data, it isn't surprising you're getting the same rows in the same order. However, this does not mean you should rely on this ordering. If you do something to change the data's layout on the disk (e.g., back it up and restore it, or even rebuild the tables' indexes), you're likely to get a different ordering.

Comment: Would collation, or charset factor in here?  or do those setting affect only when sorting a column with `order by`

Comment: It might - if the data is retrieved from an index, it is inherently stored in a sorted way, so collation **might** come into play.

Comment: thanks. I guess I am gonna have to find out the sorting order that makes business sense..and add it explicitly.

Comment: @Mecon: you don't even need to "do" something to the data. Postgres has a feature called "synchronized seq scan", which means one query can re-use a currently running seq-scan on a table even halfway through. Which means that two concurrently executing SELECT statement may return the data in a completely different order even though nothing has changed on disk and both are using the same execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

To know what really DBMS does one should look at the PLAN. The output order will depend upon it too. However there are two things to remember: first, if the plan includes 'full (heap) table scan' then the order is undefined (as DBMS may freely reorder heap data); second, the plan may change significantly if you change your SQL statement or update DB stats. This is why you should not rely on output order's stability in a long run.

Comment: The order is ***always*** undefined if there is no `order by`. No execution plan will change that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not really. Some plans implicitly define the order, some not. But the problem is that it's sometimes hard (or even impossible) to achieve needed order without `order by` and to fix the plan than just to add `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the order of the clustered index if the table has one. However this is not something that should be trusted, as the documentation say.

Comment: Postgres does not have clustered indexes

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of sql server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   Postgres has this CLUSTER command: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-cluster.html     Is it not the same thing?

Comment: @Mecon: no it's not the same as a clustered index