# How is it possible for this Python query to alternate between two different results?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am executing the following code,

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

@contextmanager
def get_psyopg2_connection(server='my_server', port=1234, read_only=True):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("<connection_string>")
        conn.set_session(readonly=read_only, autocommit=True)
        yield conn
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(e) from e
    finally:
        conn.close()

if __name__=="__main__":

    with get_psyopg2_connection() as conn_dev:

        df = pd.read_sql("""select last_value from public.lime_boxes_id_seq""", conn_dev)
        print(df)
```

and I receive two different results; last_value = 6 (correct) and 33 (incorrect). When I run the same code several times, I might get a result sequence like 6, 6, 6, 33, 33, 6. It's unpredictable.

When I execute this query in DBeaver, I always get 6.

How could this be happening?

Edit:

This table is a sequence and no one is accessing this schema except for myself. Here is the content

| last_value | log_cnt | is_called |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 27 | true |

Comment: Can you share a sample of the contents in the `public.lime_boxes_id_seq` table as a textually-formatted table in the body of your quesiton? Is `33` actually a value contained in the `last_value` attribute of some row in the table? Can you share the logic you followed to get to the idea that `6` is the "*correct*" value that *should* be returned in this context? You haven't specified any `ORDER BY` clause; as such ordering of returned records is not guaranteed (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038587/how-does-postgres-order-the-results-when-order-by-is-not-provided)).

Comment: Is it possible `my_server` is actually a load balancer for a Postgres cluster that hasn't been replicated across nodes properly, and therefore are returning different results for the same query when re-connecting each time you run this script? It would explain entirely the reason your DBeaver client gets the same result each time (it's probably not connecting/disconnecting/reconnecting between queries, potentially to different servers each time and likely maintaining the same connection between queries), but your code (which connects/disconnects/reconnects each execution) does not.

Comment: Was the value in question ever `33`? If so, is it possible there is some sort of caching mechanism between your code and the database server that is returning this erroneous data? If it was cached and never released, this could also be a reason why this data isn't returning what you believe it should, and a cache flush/reconfiguration would be necessary.

Comment: @esqew Yes, `my_server` is a load balancer for development work.

Comment: If that is in fact the case (a somewhat lucky guess, I must admit) I would recommend verifying the integrity of each of the nodes behind the load balancing appliance/configuration to ensure the data matches across nodes. This to me sounds like a replication issue among one or more of the cluster's nodes that your load balancer is connecting you through to on some sessions, but not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 distinct possibilities that stand out to me:

1. **There are multiple records in `public.lime_boxes_id_seq`**, and since you haven't specified an `ORDER BY` clause, the database will not guarantee the order in which the records are returned. While this is definitely a low likelihood, it's still worth exploring what data the table being queried *actually* contains and to work from there.
2. **The database server in question (`my_server`) is actually some sort of load balancer for a cluster of Postgres nodes behind it, and there is one or more nodes that have fallen out of sync with the rest and is returning old/incorrect data.** This would explain entirely the reason your DBeaver client gets the same result each time (it's probably not connecting/disconnecting/reconnecting between queries, potentially to different servers each time and likely maintaining the same connection between queries), but your code (which connects/disconnects/reconnects each execution) does not. To alleviate this, you can connect to a known-good node in the cluster (if your networking setup permits such an arrangement), or fix the replication issue that causes the staleness of the data.
3. If the value in question was ever 33, it might be possible **there is some sort of caching mechanism in the network between your code and the table in Postgres that is returning this erroneous data.** If it was cached by this appliance/these appliances and hasn't been flushed since then, this could also be a reason why this data isn't returning what you believe it should, and a cache flush/reconfiguration would be necessary.

Comment: Thanks @esqew! #2. addresses the issue. `my_server` is a load balancer, and I just tested connecting to the two individual servers it employs. One had a result of 6, the other, 33.